# jQuery split() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have problam idont know why bat i see all time "undefined" in all "field_input"

when i try to add from jquery .split

```js
function field_include()
{
  var form_id = $( ".form" ).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/field_include.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      form_id : form_id
    },
    success: function(data) {

      var fields = data;
      var field = fields.split(";").filter(Boolean);
      $.each(field, function(i, val){
        var field_val = val.split(",");
        $( ".addfromform" ).append('<div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label mt10">'+field_val[2]+'</label><div class="col-xs-10"><label for="'+field_val[1]+'" class="field prepend-icon"><input type="'+field_val[0]+'" name="'+field_val[1]+'" id="first_name" class="gui-input" placeholder="'+field_val[3]+'" autocomplete="off"><label for="'+field_val[1]+'" class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label></label></div></div>').fadeIn('slow');
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

string from "field_include.php":

```
1,first_name,First Name:,First Name,1;1,last_name,Last Name:,Last Name,2;1,email,Email:,Email,3;1,job,Job title:,Job title,4;
```

how i can fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chaining `.filter(Boolean)` to `fields.split(";")` to remove empty string `""` at last index of `field` where character at last index of string is `";"` which would return `undefined` at `var field_input = val.split(',');` as `val` would be empty string `""`

```
var field = fields.split(";").filter(Boolean);
```

---

```js
var fields = "1,first_name,First Name:,First Name,1;1,last_name,Last Name:,Last Name,2;1,email,Email:,Email,3;1,job,Job title:,Job title,4;";

var field1 = fields.split(";");

var field2 = fields.split(";").filter(Boolean);

$.each(field2, function(i, val) {

  var field_val = val.split(",");

  $("body").append('<div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label mt10">' + field_val[2] + '</label><div class="col-xs-10"><label for="' + field_val[1] + '" class="field prepend-icon"><input type="' + field_val[0] + '" name="' + field_val[1] + '" id="first_name" class="gui-input" placeholder="' + field_val[3] + '" autocomplete="off"><label for="' + field_val[1] + '" class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label></label></div></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @eyal Can describe _"not work"_ ? What is result ? What is logged at `console` ?

Comment: Does not display anything in console

Comment: @eyal See updated post , included stacksnippets to demonstrate . Note, `.filter(Boolean)` not necessary at at `var field_val = val.split(",");` within `$.each()`

Comment: how i can reset all time the div?

Comment: @eyal _"how i can reset all time the div?"_ ? Not certain interpret "reset all time" correctly ? What is expected result ?